# What does "10% cumulative chance" mean in the description of a potion of longevity?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, potions

The DMG description of Potion of Longevity says:

> When you drink this potion, your physical age is reduced by 1d6 + 6 years, to a minimum of 13 years.  Each time you subsequently drink a *potion of longevity* there is a 10 percent cumulative chance that you instead age by 1d6 + 6 years.

What does a 10% cumulative chance mean in this context?

Assuming that it means the chance increases by 10% each time, I find the statement awkward because usually when you state a cumulative probability, you are stating the total, not the amount that is added. That is, if we are to add 10% each time, then after 3 uses, there's actually a 20% cumulative probability that it ages you (not a 10% cumulative probability).

By a strict reading, I'd read that the probability is 10% each time after the first, but that is almost certainly not what was intended.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*[Cumulative](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cumulative) chance* does mean that the chance accumulates each time, yes. Each time you drink it after the first, there is a chance that it will age you instead of youth-en you. That chance is 10% initially, but increases by 10% each time.

So the first time you drink it, it has its normal effect. The second time, there's a 10% chance it has the opposite effect and ages you. The third time, a 20% chance of aging. The next time, a 30% chance; the next 40%. And so on.

This chance doesn't ever reset, it just accumulates.

(This does seem to be a pretty poor *potion of **longevity***. The local Better Magical Business Bureau will probably need to open an investigation into deceptive advertising and naming practices.)

As for the wording, this isn't actually incorrect, perhaps just unfamiliar. A "cumulative chance" can be used as part of a statement of an observed or imposed rule or physical law, or it can be used as part of a sentence describing the current state of a cumulative chance. The normal usage is the former, with the latter being derivative of the former and more often seen in summaries or after-the-fact status reports and similar contexts. The default meaning of "cumulative chance" is describing how the chance accumulates, and is what should be assumed if in doubt.